# Configuring Jetty 9.2 to allow symlinks through XML file

Tags: java, jetty

My setup is a bit complicated, as I use JRuby with [Warbler](https://github.com/jruby/warbler) which uses Jetty 9.2.9 underneath.

Now, [the docs for enabling symlinks in Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#file-alias-serving) tell you to add this to `WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml`:

```
  <!-- Allow symbolic links  -->
  <Call name="addAliasCheck">
    <Arg><New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AllowSymLinkAliasChecker"/></Arg>
  </Call>
```

However, as far as I can tell from searching through XML files on GitHub which use `AllowSymLinkAliasChecker`, this snippet has to be used within a `<Configure id="wac" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">` element.

Through Warbler I have access to only three files:

- `web.xml` which has `<web-app>` element
- `webserver.xml` which has `<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">` element
- `webserver.properties` which defines a bunch of args for the Jetty runner

So my question is, with access to only these three files (and possibly being able to add more of them to the `WEB-INF` directory), how can I make Jetty follow symlinks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uff, okay, so apparently if I need to configure WebAppContext, I can just add `jetty-web.xml` to my `WEB-INF` folder and [Jetty will automatically use it](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#jetty-web-xml-config).

So in the end my `jetty-web.xml` looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE 
Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN"
"http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<!-- https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#jetty-web-xml-config -->
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <!-- https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#file-alias-serving -->
  <Call name="addAliasCheck">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AllowSymLinkAliasChecker" />
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```